# MSMQ:How can i know whether the message has reach the destination when send messages in a transaction?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I have two machines A and B,A is used for sending message while B is used for receiving message.
Now,i power off B so the message sent out by A is store in outgoing queue.My question is:

1.As a developer,how can i know the message has reach B?(when B is not available,the application that send the message exit as usual,no exceptions were thrown)

2.How to resend the message in outgoing queue when B is start?

Comment: The whole point of using technology like MSMQ is to decouple applications. MSMQ takes care of making every send look successful (unless the local disk is full) and for getting the message across to the correct server as and when it *is* available. Either you've picked the wrong technology for your requirements, or you've misunderstood your responsibilities when it comes to messaging.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  the message stuck in the outgoing queue after machine B start，how can i resend the message

Comment: You don't resend the message. You fix your MSMQ configuration. E.g. maybe [this KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2554746) applies to your situation? MSMQ *should* handle this, so if it isn't doing it, you *fix* MSMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically speaking, MSMQ is a technology for sending messages into an asynchronous manner and more importantly, into a disconnected fashion (the receiver maybe is NOT connected to the system yet).

The sender, if he doesn't receive a MessageQueueException (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeueexception(v=vs.110).aspx) then he can consider that the message is sent successfully. If you really want to see in "real time" whether B received a message from A or not, you should rely on other communication technologies (direct TCP connection or something that wraps a TCP communication channel, such as .NET Remoting or WCF).

As I said, B maybe is not online yet or has been shut down for no matter what reasons ... So for your second question, I can tell you that you don't have any problems because whenever B restarts, it should call again "Receive" on your queue (to dequeue any message sent by A).

Read the following link: http://www.primaryobjects.com/2007/08/13/using-the-microsoft-message-queue-msmq-and-c-asp-net/ I think it is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

"As a developer, how can I know the message has reach B?"


Journaling is what you need.
[Writing in MSMQ's personal journal](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/22/writing-in-msmq-s-personal-journal.aspx)

"How to resend the message in outgoing queue when B is start?"


Delivery of messages in outgoing queues is looked after by MSMQ. You don't need to resend. Just wait for the destination to come online.